# ¿Por qué la función de dispatch se ejecuta infinitamente y vuelve lenta la página?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy usando react redux con ducks y quiero que al acceder a esa ruta se me carguen todos los proyectos, lo que sucede es que no sé cómo ejecutar el dispatch sin que tenga que usar el evento onClick, solo quiero que se carguen los datos al entrar a esa ruta.  Lo hice pero me genera un interminable ciclo donde se ejecuta la función dispatch.

[image: esta imagen es mi componente projects.jsx]

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {getProjectsAction} from '../redux/projectDucks';

const Projects = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const projects = useSelector(store => store.projects.array)

    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(getProjectsAction())
    }, 0);

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid p-5">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <h3>Lista de Proyectos</h3>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
                        data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
                        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <form className="d-flex">
                        <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Nuevo</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre Proyecto</th>
                        <th>formaVenta</th>
                        <th>estado</th>
                        <th>tipoProyecto</th>
                        <th>totalUnidades</th>
                        <th>fechaInicioVenta</th>
                        <th>fechaInioConstruccion</th>
                        <th>fechaEntrega</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        projects.map(item => (
                            <tr key={item._id}>
                                <td>{item.name}</td>
                                <td>{item.formaVenta}</td>
                                <td>{item.estado}</td>
                                <td>{item.tipoProyecto}</td>
                                <td>{item.totalUnidades}</td>
                                <td>{item.fechaInicioVenta}</td>
                                <td>{item.fechaInioConstruccion}</td>
                                <td>{item.fechaEntrega}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button 
                                        className="button muted-button"
                                    > 
                                        Edit
                                    </button>  
                                    <button 
                                        className="button muted-button"
                                    >
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>  
        </div>
    )
}

export default Projects
```

Estoy usando setTimout para ejecutar el dispatch, muestra los datos pero se vuelve pesada la página y siempre se está ejecutando la función.

Comment: El código va como texto, por favor.

Comment: listo, ya lo edite.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar useEffect para hacer esto:

```
useEffect(() =>{
  dispatch(getProjectsAction())
},[])
```

De este modo solo se ejecutará la primera vez que renderize el componente.